# "setText: is deprecated" warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-warnings

When I run my app, a warning pops up that says "'setText:' is deprecated.how can i rewrite this line of code to get rid of the error?

```
cell.text = [moreArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a documentation question.  Anytime you have a question about this sort of thing look at the documentation.  It always tells you what to do when a method is depreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [moreArray objectAtIndex:row];
```